# Help with a question regarding basis and dimension?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am presented with:

> Let $a_1$ and $a_2$ be linearly independent vectors in $R^3$ and let x be a vector in $R^2$.
>
> a) Describe geometrically Span($a_1, a_2$)
>
> b) If A=($a_1,a_2$) and b=Ax, then what is the dimension of Span($a_1, a_2$, b)? Explain.

For a), since there are only two vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$, wouldn't the Span($a_1, a_2$) only be a plane in $R^3$?

For b), since b can be represented as b=Ax, wouldn't the dimension of Span($a_1, a_2$, b) only be 2 because b is linearly dependent?

These are really only guesses at the questions. I'm having a terrible time understanding span, spaces, basis, and dimension (as well as most of linear algebra in general). Can anyone either confirm or reject my answers and perhaps provide a little more information?

Comment: You need to say "$b$ is linearly dependent on $a_1$ and $a_2$" (or "$a_1,a_2,b$ are linearly dependent"), since $b=Ax$ makes $b$ a linear combination of $a_1$ and $a_2$. Otherwise what you say makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ad a)    Yes, you are right, it is just a plane in $\mathbb R^3$. Maybe you want to be a bit more precise and say *which* plane it is? It will be a plane containing the origin, for example. And it will be the *unique* plane that contains the vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$. Convince yourself that any point in this plane can be written as a combination of the $a_i$ and that they are the only ones!

Ad b)   Again correct. If $x=(x_1,x_2)$, then $Ax$ is nothing else but $Ax=x_1a_1+x_2a_2$ (this is purely algebraic). Thus $b$ already lives in the plane described in a).

As a remark: don't despair. It is completely normal to be confused by these things when you encouter them for the first time. Just keep asking yourself similar questions and it will become very intuitive quickly!